# MySQL DATE_FORMAT reverse?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am using MySQL DATE_FORMAT function to grab the date in the format i need it in. as the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dob`, '%m-%d-%Y' ) as dob FROM `tblUsersProfile` WHERE `user_id` = 1
```

But now i want to update the date from this format to the default mysql date format?

I know how to do this in php, but iam trying to change the format in MySQL. Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE()` function:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
UPDATE tblUsersProfile SET `dob` = STR_TO_DATE('1-2-2011', '%m-%d-%Y') WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Isn't string to date function using Unix timestamp and is limited to 1970.

Comment: No, see the documentation link. It parses a date in the format specified in the second param into a mysql date.